# How to AddHandler upon matching HTTP host condition?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to add the following line into `.htaccess`:

```
AddHandler fcgid54-script .php
```

Except, I only want this line to run when my domain name is `www.example.com`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add fcgi handler to all php files using mod-rewrite's H flag :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule \.php$ - [H=fcgid54-script]
```

On apache 2.4 and later, you can also accomplish this using If directive.

```
<if "%{HTTP_HOST} ='www.example.com'">
AddHandler fcgid54-script .php
</if>
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working for me - I'm getting an error.

Comment: do you have any idea why the first section of code isn't working for me? it's giving me a 500 error when I include that section of code in my `.htaccess`.

Comment: @Think123 Sorry it was due to a syntex error. try the fixed rule.

Comment: Thanks @Anubhava sir!!